# Change hostname on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3 for VMware

Tags: linux, command-line, configuration, opensuse, suse

I want to update the hostname for one of my VMware virtual machines running SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3 for VMware .

I tried changing the hostname using YaST but after reboot the old name came back.

I tried `echo "newhostname > /etc/HOSTNAME"` but after reboot this also goes.

I also tried `hostname newhostname` but this was also lost after reboot.

How can I make the change permanent?

Comment: In yast, [uncheck the `change hostname via DHCP` tick box](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_sle_admin/data/sec_basicnet_yast.html#sec_basicnet_yast_change_host)

Comment: It is already Unchecked change hostname via DHCP

│[ ] Change Hostname via DHCPNo interface with dhcp

Comment: Does your virtual machine use DHCP? How are you checking the hostname - via the `hostname` command?

Comment: No, This machine is having static IP. Yes host name command shows me my hostname as myworkspace after reboot. Even kernel shows new name before reboot, but after reboot revert to old name.
myworkspace:/ # more /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
go

Comment: In SLES_11 hostname is in /proc/sys/kernel/hostname ;)

Answer (score 3):

To change the hostname on a SUSE system you need to change the following files:

- `/etc/HOSTNAME`
- `/etc/hosts`

You may also have other configuration files where it's stored (e.g., `postfix` configuration files), so a `grep -R` for the old hostname in `/etc` is probably a good idea:

```
grep -R <oldhostname> /etc
```

where *<oldhostname>* is the old hostname).

Comment: no files shows where its reflecting to old hostname in /etc after doing the changes. But after reboot again old hostname shows:

Comment: After reboot old hostname shows
Before Change
myworkspace:~ # grep -R myworkspace /etc
/etc/hosts.YaST2save:10.196.5.68  myworkspace.kaec.net myworkspace
/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch:ES_UNICAST_HOSTS=myworkspace.kaec.net
/etc/hosts.orig:10.196.5.68  myworkspace.kaec.net myworkspace
Binary file /etc/krb5.keytab matches
Binary file /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key matches
/etc/HOSTNAME:myworkspace.kaec.net

After Chnage
myworkspace:~ # grep -R myworkspace /etc
/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch:ES_UNICAST_HOSTS=myworkspace.kaec.net
Binary file /etc/krb5.keytab matches
Binary file /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key matches

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `hostnamectl set-hostname (hostname)` command. Do not include the brackets that is a placeholder for the hostname. Then restart your terminal for it to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out that the more standard file is `/etc/hostname`.  SuSE uses a symlink to point `/etc/HOSTNAME` to this file, so a script which wrote  to `/etc/hostname` (perhaps because it was designed to run in multiplpe distributions of Linux/Unix) would work if it wrote to `/etc/hostname`.

Comment: This is the right direction. Here is all I need to do to have the hostname persist across reboots: https://gist.github.com/phunehehe/4481a7ae440e0fa571e6ea467582b1c2.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed even yast doesn't set the hostname when
I used lowercase chars for the hostname part. 
Uppercase chars worked.

To up the chances, also did a 
/etc/init.d/network restart,
followed by a logout/login.

Try this to help your script. I've already lost an hour
setting the hostname, so I didn't test setting the files
manually.